# SQL Server EncryptByKey with EKM Provider

Tags: sql-server, encryptbykey

I want to use the Transact-SQL command EncryptByKey in a SQL Server database. And I want to use an external key provider (EKM) to store the key.

I successfully created the symmetric key 'symmetric_key' with the command:

```
USE master ;
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY symmetric_key
FROM PROVIDER EKM_Prov
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256,
PROVIDER_KEY_NAME = 'symmetric_key' ;
GO
```

I see the key in my external key provider and in the table `sys.symmetric_keys`.

Now, I just want to encrypt some data with e.g.:

```
SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('symmetric_key'), 'Highest') AS CipherText;
```

But it always returns NULL.

Opening the key is not required for external keys, as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

What am I missing?

Do I have to bind the 'symmetric_key' to a login? If so, how?

Comment: I don't have any experience here, but surely there has to be something that governs whether a given key can be used or not. For non-EKM keys, it's a password, or whether the key that encrypts that key is open. What is the check for EKM keys?

Comment: Did you "open" the key? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql

Comment: No, I did not open it as it is not required for external keys, as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16